# Real time Prefix matching and auto-complete in Quora

Tags: search, autocomplete, pattern-matching, string-matching, prefix

How is real time autocomplete with prefix matching implemented in Quora ?

Since Solr and Sphinx doesn't support real-time updating so what changes were made to support real time updating?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's done using javascript and jquery. I grabbed a few key lines from the minified script on the Quora homepage that I think support this theory:

Here's an ajax call to a resource providing JSON data:

```
$.ajax({type:"GET",url:this.resultsQueryPath,dataType:"json",data:a,success:this.fnbind(ƒ(a){this.ajaxCallback(a)}),error:this.fnbind(ƒ(a,b,c){console.log(b,c),this.requestOutstanding=!1,this.$("#@results_shell").html("Could not retrieve results: "+b)})})}
```

note that the successful result gets put into the "a" variable. Then later here's the autocompletion based on the keydown of the "question_box" element which is completing from the parent of "a"

```
this.$ ("#@item input.question_box").keydown (ƒ (b) {
if (b.keyCode==9&&!b.shiftKey)for (var c=e.getLiveDomId (a.cid),d=a.parent ().orderedVisibleChildren (),f\^M=0;f<d.length-1;++f)if (c==d [f]) {
$ (this).blur (),$ ("#"+d [f+1]+" input.question_box").focus ();return!1}
})
```

I think this is pretty incontrovertible, but it would still be nice to have the un-minified script to compare. For instance I can't see where resultsQueryPath comes from (I can't locate it's source, may be intentionally obfuscated).

Comment: Thats the main question...how does result get put into the "a" variable, client side autocomplete is no big deal when you have small set of result. my question is regarding real time prefix matching at backend.

Comment: Ah I see what you're getting at, good point. I think Quora has around 200,000 questions and those couldn't all be loaded client side. I don't work at Quora so I can't really speculate.